# Liquibase-generated SQL gives ORA-01735 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, liquibase, oracle12c

I am running the following changeset on an Oracle 12 database (the latest official docker image). When the changeset is executed, I get a SQL error:

```
Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
 [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE TEST.LANGUAGE ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_C0010528 PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX TEST.SYS_C0010528]
```

I generated the changeset from an existing Oracle database schema using Liquibase tools, with minor alterations.

***Does liquibase not support Oracle 12?***

***How do I configure liquibase to generate Oracle 12-compatible SQL?***

***Is this a settings issue, or a bug in Liquibase?***

Details:

It looks like Oracle doesn't accept the qualifier for the index name in the USING INDEX statement. The following revised SQL seems to work as intended:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST.LANGUAGE ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_C0010528 PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX SYS_C0010528
```

Here is the changeset definition:

```
<changeSet author="rmorrise (generated)" id="1507039841670-7">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <primaryKeyExists tableName="LANGUAGE"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createIndex indexName="SYS_C0010528" tableName="LANGUAGE" unique="true">
        <column name="ID"/>
    </createIndex>
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="ID" constraintName="SYS_C0010528" forIndexName="SYS_C0010528" tableName="LANGUAGE"/>
</changeSet>
```

**Update:**

I fixed the `<addPrimaryKey>` entries by replacing them with `<sql>` tags, but I got the same error on `<addUniqueConstraint>` with `forIndexName`.

Here is the generated SQL to create the index. It appears to be created in the same schema.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST.UK46FCA532E38E4F92860631AA28CB ON TEST.MESSAGE_ROLE(TEMPLATE_ID, LABEL);

ALTER TABLE TEST.MESSAGE_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT UK46FCA532E38E4F92860631AA28CB UNIQUE (TEMPLATE_ID, LABEL) USING INDEX TEST.UK46FCA532E38E4F92860631AA28CB;
```

To answer Alex's question about the use of system object names: The schema was originally generated by hbm2ddl and migrated to liquibase using `generateChangelog`.

A query to dba_objects confirms that the OWNER is *TEST*.

Comment: That implies the index is being created under a different schema, which is odd; can you see the generated statement for that, who owns the index according to `dba_objects`; and which user are you executing all these (qualified and unqualified) statements as? SYS maybe? (This may be a Liquibase thing, but why are you creating the index separately, and why are you using what is normally a system-generated name instead of something more meaningful?)

Comment: Oracle does accept a schema name for the index in the USING INDEX statement. [It's in the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE), and works fine for me.

Comment: Updated to answer @AlexPoole's comments. kfinity I have no explanation for this behavior, I only know that when I edit out the schema name, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and as I was reading this topic I see that we both named our schema "TEST".
I changed the schema's name and it worked immediatly.